# VBA store msoThemeColor in variable

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am looking to store mso theme colors in a variable so that the chart colors and patterns can change dynamically (variable Th in this situation). Here is my current code:

```
Dim Th As Long
Th = "msoThemeColorAccent" & ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0)
If ActiveCell = "Realized" Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Srs).Select

    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Th
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
       .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Th
    End With
End If
```

I'm thinking the problem here is that I am not using the correct Dim categorization. I've seen questions on here on storing RGB as variables (using Dim Long seemed to be the solution) but nothing on msoThemeColors yet. Thanks and let me know if I can provide any other details!

Comment: "I'm thinking the problem here is..." are you getting an error with your code? Or is it just not working like you expect it to?  If an error, what error at what line?

Comment: Sorry - basically the variable Th is not being recognized. No error message. It's not picking up the right msothemecolor

Comment: Remove the `as Long` and see what happens if it just defaults to `Variant` (alternatively, try `String`).  Also, make sure the offset cell is between 1 and 6.

Comment: You're assigning a `String` to a variable (`Th` ...seriously consider giving it a meaningful name... pixels are free, a headscratching developer isn't) that's declared `As Long`. This is bound to fail. Declare it `As String` if you want to use it as a string. `Long` is a 32-bit integer type.

Comment: in addition to what @Mat'sMug suggested, I also believe that the `msoThemeColorAccent*n*` is really just an enumeration and not an actual string. You may want to find the enumerations and assign the `Long` enumeration value based on the cell value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since msoThemeColorAccent is an enumeration, the below refactored code will work.

```
Dim lThemeColor As Long
lThemeColor = ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0) + 4
'msoThemeColor1 enum is 5, 2 is 6, 3 is 7 ... so add 4 to the value 

If ActiveCell = "Realized" Then

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Srs).Format
        With .Fill
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = lThemeColor
            .Solid
        End With
        With .Line
           .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = lThemeColor
        End With
    End With

End If
```

Comment: I ended up going with Scott's solution but Mat's explanation helped me to understand in and out. Thanks everyone for the awesome help!!

Comment: @JKo_FinanceUse - I am glad you got your answer. I would suggest studying Mat's answer thoroughly though. There's a ton of great coding practices in there.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to tell what's going on, because your code relies heavily on *default members*. Anyway:

```
Dim Th As Long
```

This is correct.

```
Dim themeColorIndex As MsoThemeColorIndex
```

This is correct *and* explicit (see [MsoThemeColorIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/microsoft.office.core.msothemecolorindex.aspx) on MSDN).

As [Scott Holtzman said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130741/vba-store-msothemecolor-in-variable#comment63694346_38130741), the possible values here are `Enum` values, not strings: you simply cannot generate the correct value by concatenating strings into one of the defined `Enum` names.

So by doing this:

> ```
> Th = "msoThemeColorAccent" & ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0)
> ```

My guess is that `ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0)` must contain a number between 1 and 6. That's a dangerous assumption to make: `ActiveCell` could be literally *anything*. If that value is in a specific cell, refer to it by its address:

```
themeColorIndex = Sheet1.Range("B12").Value
```

This is *slightly* better, but it still assumes that the value in `B12` can be implicitly converted to a `Long` integer.

```
Dim selectedValue As Variant
selectedValue = Sheet1.Range("B12").Value
If Not IsNumeric(selectedValue) Then 
    MsgBox "Invalid value!"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Sheet1.Range("E12").Value <> "Realized" Then Exit Sub

Dim themeColorIndex As MsoThemeColorIndex
themeColorIndex = selectedValue
```

If you're only interested in `msoThemeColorAccent1` through `msoThemeColorAccent6`, then you'll want `B12` to contain values `5` through `10`, which are the *underlying enum values* that you're looking for.

If your worksheet, for usability reasons, must allow values `1` through `6`, then you can do this:

```
Dim themeColorIndex As MsoThemeColorIndex
'msoThemeColorAccent1 underlying value is 5, so we add 4 to the value:
themeColorIndex = selectedValue + 4
```

Then you're making *another* dangerous assumption: you assume that there's an active chart! Assuming the chart exists in `Sheet1`, you'd much better refer to it, again, explicitly:

```
Dim theChart As ChartObject
Set theChart = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
With theChart.SeriesCollection(srs) 'whatever srs means
    With .Format
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = themeColorIndex
        .Fill.Solid
        .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = themeColorIndex
    End With
End With
```

Comment: wish I could give +10 for going above and beyond :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think [codereview.se] has forever tinted the way I'm answering on SE =)

Comment: I ended up going with Scott's solution but Mat's explanation helped me to understand in and out. Thanks everyone for the awesome help!!

Comment: @JKo_FinanceUse if you now have working code, I'd suggest you put it up on [codereview.se] to make it fail-safe and easier to maintain. Cheers!